# Problemas com a sincronização do git

Tags: git, github

Meu amigo fez um fork no meu codigo e para atualizar os dados tanto no repositório dele como no meu, a gente ta tendo que criar dois remote um pra cada repositório e usar push/pull nos dois. Como fazer para que fique apenas um remote?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível ter um único remote se existem dois repositórios distintos. Cada remote é o endereço remoto dos repositórios.

O fork de um repositório possibilita ter o controle sobre ele, fazer as alterações necessárias de edição ou apagar arquivos. Isso por que não temos acesso ao repositório original. Essa é uma estratégia muito comum em projetos Open Source, pois possibilita você ter acesso a pegar o código original, ter uma estrutura de repositório e manter um repositório a parte, sem fazer qualquer dano ao original.

Portanto se os dois desenvolvedores tem acesso ao repositório original essa estratégia não precisa ser utilizada!

No caso de quererem ter essa estratégia, o segundo desenvolvedor não precisa ter acesso ao primeiro repositório. Para devolver o código para este repositório pode ser criado um *Pull-request*.

**Pull-request**

É uma estratégia de devolver código a um repositório original, a origem do *fork*, sem precisar ter acesso de escrita no repositório original. Normalmente o fluxo seria o seguinte, assumindo que se está usando o Github como storage dos repositórios Git:

1. *Fork* do repositório na conta do segundo desenvolvedor
2. *Clone* do repositório *"forkado"* para a máquina do desenvolvedor
3. Alteracões necessárias no código, *commit*, e *push* para o repositório *"forkado"*
4. Criação de um *pull-request* do segundo repositório para o orignal do código alterado
5. O mantenedor do repositório original analisa o código enviando e aceita o *pr*, colocando assim o código no repositório original.

Entenda que o *pull-request* é uma feature dos *"storages"* de repositórios, pois é uma função que faz um pull para um repositório de um código que está sendo enviado. Ele foi desenvolvido pelo [Github](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-requests#about-pull-requests), mas está presente no [Azure DevOps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops), e outros sistemas.